# Is it possible to call window.print() from Webview of VSCode extension?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I have standalone app which has "Print" html  button. And I'm rendering this page also into my VSCode extension. But when I click on print button doesn't happend into VSCode.

Also I've tried to emulate print html mechanism into VSCode DevConsole, but getting error:
[image]

Is it possible somehow to print html page which is rendering into webview of my VSCode extension?

Answer (score 0):

ok, seems I've got official answer on [Github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/issues/320#issuecomment-646383360):

> No, we don't support printing from webviews and do not have plans to add support.
>   You could try using a native module to control printing